# Create WPF TextBox that accepts only Text

Tags: wpf

```
private void txtLastName_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsDigit((char)e.Key)) e.Handled = true;
    }
```

But It not support all key in keyboard .

Comment: Which characters don't you want to accept? E.g. @:;_--#()/\.,?!''" or numbers too?

Comment: I want to input only text.

Answer (score 5):

```
    private void txtLastName_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(e.Text, "^[a-zA-Z]"))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience. Please edit your answer to include [clarification, context and try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

You must use `IsLetter`.

```
private void txtLastName_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Char.IsLetter((char)e.Key)) e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This thread is really old, but if someone still needs it, here is code that is working for me

(Edited a little bit Usman's code)

```
private void TextValidationTextBox(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
      Regex regex = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z]+");
      e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
}
```

And don't forget to put code below to TextBox that you want to accept only text ( in xaml )

```
PreviewTextInput="TextValidationTextBox"
```